# Delete the entire row if the a value in value is equal to previous row in R

Tags: r, duplicates

I am new to R programming and I need a help to delete the entire row based on the value of a single column. I want to delete the row, if a value in a single column is equal to the previous row value.

The following is my data,

```
   x.id x.timestamp x.count
71    1  1435114605      61
72    1  1435114606      61
73    1  1435114659      61
74    1  1435114719      62
75    1  1435114726      62
76    1  1435114780      62
77    1  1435155998      62
78    1  1435156059      62
79    1  1435156076      62
80    1  1435156119      62
```

Here I want to delete the rows based on the x$x.count value.

My Output should be,

```
   x.id x.timestamp x.count
71    1  1435114605      61
74    1  1435114719      62
```

I cant use duplicated or unique function here because later on the same values repeat in the data set. I just want to remove the data based on the previous value.

Comment: With data.table, one option is `library(data.table);setDT(dat)[as.logical(x.count-shift(x.count, fill=x.count[1L]-1))]`  It should be very fast.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `diff` to find where differences between consecutive rows are greater than 0 (plus the first row).  Maybe use `!=0` if the `x.count` isn't sorted.

```
dat[c(T, diff(dat$x.count)>0), ]

#    x.id x.timestamp x.count
# 71    1  1435114605      61
# 74    1  1435114719      62
```

Comment: @ijazahamed You may want to simply translate the answer to `data.table` if your data is so large.

Comment: you're missing a paren by the looks of it.

Comment: Yeah my bad... Got it now.. Thanks

Comment: @nongkrong I am facing some problem here. the x.count values range from 61,62,1,3,5..... but after removing the duplicates, I am getting 61,62,3,5 only... this is because of the diff(dat$x.count)>0)..can this be changed accordingly?

Comment: @ijazahamed did you try replacing `>0` with `!=0`

Comment: When I put !=0 instead of greater than, I got the required output