# Output "NA" into a new column when string values are same as previous row

Tags: r

Using R, I'm trying to add a new column to a data set that duplicates the column to the left, replacing string values with "NA" when a string is identical to the row above.

This is probably best explained with some data. My dataset currently looks like this:

```
   x.id x.timestamp x.action
71    1  1435114605   click
72    1  1435114606   click
73    1  1435114659   click
74    1  1435114719  scroll
75    1  1435114726  scroll
76    1  1435114780  scroll
77    1  1435155998  scroll
78    1  1435156059  scroll
79    1  1435156076   click
80    1  1435156119   click
```

And the output I'm trying to get to is this:

```
   x.id x.timestamp x.action x.mutate
71    1  1435114605   click   click
72    1  1435114606   click      NA
73    1  1435114659   click      NA
74    1  1435114719  scroll  scroll
75    1  1435114726  scroll      NA
76    1  1435114780  scroll      NA
77    1  1435155998  scroll      NA
78    1  1435156059  scroll      NA
79    1  1435156076  scroll   click
80    1  1435156119  scroll      NA
```

As you can see, the right-hand column replaces duplicates with "NA". However, as the same values are repeated later I can't just use duplicated or unique functions.

#### Previous attempts

1. This is quite similar to this problem and I tried something along those lines, but as these are characters and not numericals it gave me an error: [Delete the entire row if the a value in value is equal to previous row in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31689413/delete-the-entire-row-if-the-a-value-in-value-is-equal-to-previous-row-in-r)
2. Then, I tried making the for loop show below, but got this error:
   "Error in timestamp[[i]] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable"

   ```
   for(i in 1:length(timestamp))
    {
   if (timestamp[[i]] == min(timestamp)) event_type[[i]] <- event_type[[i]]
   else if(event_type[[i + 1]] == event_type[[i]]) event_type[[i + 1]] <- "NA"
   else if(event_type[[i + 1]] != event_type[[i]]) event_type[[i + 1]] <- event_type[[i + 1]]
    }
   ```

Any ideas for how to create the extra "x.mutate" column on the second data set shown above? I am a bit lost, any help much appreciated :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you append FALSE (since the first item is never a sequential duplicate) as the first item to vector of equalities of `head` and `tail`, that can be used at a test vector for `is.na<-`. The `is.na<-` function use the logical vector on the RHS of the assignment operator to specify which entries in the vector inside the parentheses gets reassigned to NA:

```
 dfrm$mutate <- dfrm$x.action  # Make copy to modify
 is.na( dfrm$mutate) <- c(FALSE, head(dfrm$x.action,-1)==tail(dfrm$x.action,-1) )

dfrm
       x.id x.timestamp x.action mutate
71    1  1435114605    click  click
72    1  1435114606    click   <NA>
73    1  1435114659    click   <NA>
74    1  1435114719   scroll scroll
75    1  1435114726   scroll   <NA>
76    1  1435114780   scroll   <NA>
77    1  1435155998   scroll   <NA>
78    1  1435156059   scroll   <NA>
79    1  1435156076    click  click
80    1  1435156119    click   <NA>
```

Comment: Many thanks! I used this solution in the end as it seemed to work most easily with my dataset. However, many thanks to Konrad Rudolph, tmfmnk and G. Grothendieck for their solutions. And happy holidays to anyone celebrating :-)

Answer (score 3):

**1) rleid/ave** Using the data shown reproducibly in the Note at the end and making use of `rleid` in the data.table package we define a function `x1_na` which replaces all elements of its vector argument with NA except the first and then apply it with `ave`:

```
library(data.table)

x1_na <- function(x) `length<-`(x[1], length(x))
transform(DF, x.mutate = ave(x.action, rleid(x.action), FUN = x1_na))
```

giving:

```
   x.id x.timestamp x.action x.mutate
71    1  1435114605    click    click
72    1  1435114606    click     <NA>
73    1  1435114659    click     <NA>
74    1  1435114719   scroll   scroll
75    1  1435114726   scroll     <NA>
76    1  1435114780   scroll     <NA>
77    1  1435155998   scroll     <NA>
78    1  1435156059   scroll     <NA>
79    1  1435156076    click    click
80    1  1435156119    click     <NA>
```

**2) rleid/duplicated** A variation of the above would be:

```
transform(DF, x.mutate = replace(x.action, duplicated(rleid(x.action)), NA))
```

**3) Base R** The only non-base part of the above is `rleid` so if you need a base R solution use one of the above but define `rleid` yourself like this:

```
rleid <- function(x) with(rle(x), rep(seq_along(lengths), lengths))
```

### Note

We assume the input is the following shown in reproducible form. In particular note that the last column is character (as stated in the question in the Previous attempts section of the question).

```
Lines <- "
   x.id x.timestamp x.action
71    1  1435114605   click
72    1  1435114606   click
73    1  1435114659   click
74    1  1435114719  scroll
75    1  1435114726  scroll
76    1  1435114780  scroll
77    1  1435155998  scroll
78    1  1435156059  scroll
79    1  1435156076   click
80    1  1435156119   click"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, as.is = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

With `dplyr` you can do:

```
df %>%
 mutate(res = ifelse(x.action == lag(x.action) & row_number() != min(row_number()), NA, x.action))

   x.id x.timestamp x.action    res
1     1  1435114605    click  click
2     1  1435114606    click   <NA>
3     1  1435114659    click   <NA>
4     1  1435114719   scroll scroll
5     1  1435114726   scroll   <NA>
6     1  1435114780   scroll   <NA>
7     1  1435155998   scroll   <NA>
8     1  1435156059   scroll   <NA>
9     1  1435156076    click  click
10    1  1435156119    click   <NA>
```

Or in a simplified way (as proposed by @Konrad Rudolph):

```
df %>%
 mutate(res = ifelse(x.action == lag(x.action, default = ""), NA, x.action))
```

It just compares whether "x.action" has the same value as the previous "x.action". For the first row it just assigns its value from "x.action".

Comment: Isn’t `min(row_number())` just `1L`? And why `paste0(x.action)` instead of just `x.action`?

Comment: In fact, the following works just as well: `df %>% mutate(res = ifelse(x.action == lag(x.action, default = ''), NA, x.action))`